# ./ngrok http 5000 bash: ./ngrok: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ngrok, rasa-nlu, facebook-chatbot

how to solve this problem

command == ./ngrok http 5000
 bash: ./ngrok: No such file or directory

Comment: I think the syntax is like : `./ngrok http <ip-address/host : port>`

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to install ngrok from snap. then you can run it form anywhere.

```
sudo snap install ngrok

ngrok http 5000
```